# Java Preferences API sharing between multiple JVMs in a load balanced environment

Tags: java, jvm, load-balancing, preferences

I am using java.util.prefs.Preferences with database store. I have multiple server nodes running same application in a load balanced environment. The problem with Preferences API is when I update a preference from one of the node it reflects immediately in the database but when I load same preference on other server nodes it shows old values. To get around this I have to restart individual nodes or update preferences on each server node. I have tried sync() and flush() from Preferences API but no luck.
How can I propogate preference updates to all JVMs in load balanced environment?

Comment: Who implemented the “Preferences with database store”? This sounds much like the responsibility of whoever did this.

Comment: its very old inherited code base. But it does make sense to have shared store in load balanced environment. any suggestion on better way of implementing it?

Comment: What do you mean with “better way of implementing it”? We don’t know how it has been implemented.